# Highstock dataGrouping.approximation show count for each point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Any solution with **dataGrouping.approximation** show count (arr.length of each data per grouped) on **tooltip** or **dataLabels**, without drawing second series as in jsfiddle.
I don't find out how to accesses to the second value returned from **dataGrouping.approximation**

```
approximation:  function(arr) {
    var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    var count = arr.length;
    var average = sum/count;
    return [count, average];
},
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HappyFX/25sj770e/4/)

Comment: Have you though about making countArr as global variable? http://jsfiddle.net/25sj770e/6/

Comment: Good idea, still how we can display correct counter on point?

Comment: I think it will be possible in future Highcharts releases.  Right now the problem with an array will be with a dynamic grouping.

Comment: Any pull request? Also it's good to be able push addition data e.g. URL or other parameters in series.data to display on dataGrouping.

Comment: You can add this suggestion on Highcharts userVoice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api